# How do I extract lines starting with `Subject:` from a large number of files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to extract a single line start with `Subject:`. But the problem is I have more than 1500 .txt files in a folder. I use this python script :

```py
from glob import glob
import fileinput
import os

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    files = (os.path.join(p, f) for p, ds, fs in os.walk(os.curdir) for f in fs)
    for line in fileinput.input(files):
        if 'Subject:' in line:
            out.write(line)
```

actually its work fine. But it took lots of processing power and time. I'm looking for a replacement terminal command for this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep "Subject:" {} \; >/tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: @Germar please don't just modify my answer. Your change is valid, but it would be best as a comment: 1) your change outputs the filename as well, which per the comment on A.B.'s answer, is not what Miller wants. 2) If you put it as a comment with your rationale, we all can learn about the reason for your change, rather than my answer being modified. Thanks.

Comment: you're right. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep` with `-r` for a recursive search
and `-m1` to stop reading the file after the first match.

```
grep -rh -m1 '^Subject:' /path/to/your/folder/ > out
```

All matching lines are in `out`.

Comment: tankx A.B.  its fine. but still its the matching lines came with the file name also. i don't get the connection why its give the file name.? (eg: spmsgc66.txt:Subject: bills under control monthly bill manager 98 / 99)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Also, as you are using `*`, unless the `/path/to/your/folder/` has any subdirectories to search for,  `-r` is redundant too..

Comment: @heemayl sorry, now I'm confused. You mean `grep -rh '^Subject:' /path/to/your/folder/` is enough?

Comment: @A.B. yes..unless OP wants to search only in `/path/to/your/folder/`, in that case you need `grep -h '^Subject:' /path/to/your/folder/*.txt`  :)

Comment: You can also add `-m1`, since OP says there's only one matching line in each file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, from anywhere:

```
sed -n '/^Subject:/p' /path/to/dir/*.txt
```

From the directory containing files:

```
sed -n '/^Subject:/p' *.txt
```

`/^Subject:/` will match only lines starting with `Subject:`.

To save the output in a file:

```
sed -n '/^Subject:/p' *.txt >output.file
```